# Code in the template or in a module?

Tags: theming

Is it better to write hook functions in `template.php` (or a .inc in my theme folder) or is it better to put them in custom modules?  Or, does it matter?  Is it just a matter of organizational preference?  Does it depend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id say its simple case of organisation and relevance. Hooks fit into three different categories, alter, process and theme so probably best to organise these into separate include files.

```
inc/
template.alter.inc
template.process.inc
template.theme.inc
```

If your going to add a class to a button in a certain contrib module or similar then obviously creating a custom module is overkill.

Probably the best strategy to have is to work on the theme layer and it will soon be apparent if its worth putting the relevant code into its own module. Either way, you have achieved what you wanted.

Does it matter where the code is? Probably not, it's a few checks or calls wherever it is. Your probably get many an argument on best practices from various developers on this.

Comment: I'd argue 'relevance' is the key word in there...if the hook implementation will alter the display of something non-generic, it should go in the theme. If the functionality is global (potentially theme-independent) then it goes in a module. But yeah, you'll probably get differing opinions on this

Comment: small tweeks in display of node data, i tend to just go with `template.php`. anything more substantial like altering some hook or building a report, i put in its on mod. i guess i look at mods as functionality and `template.php` as display.

Comment: thanks @Alex Gill, @Clive and @austin. It seems like there's some consensus around using `template.php` (or related incs) for narrowly scoped, lighter-weight customizations and reserving custom modules for broadly-scoped heavy-lifting.  Sometimes `template.php` hooks can contain content related alterations, like adding Ajax to an element.  Which still seems like a `template.php` thing because it's fairly simple and scoped to the display of a specific element.  Anyway, thanks again for the comments.

Comment: It can matter where code is.  Code in a module runs on all pages; code in a theme only runs when the theme is being used on a page.  I typically do have a theme-specific module for every theme I make to handle heavy lifting, but will check `$GLOBALS['theme_key']` as needed.  Some base themes (eg, Omega) have some fancy methods for splitting things out into includes.  These are worth looking at for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to write hook functions in template.php, or is it better to put them in custom modules?

First off, themes can just implement theme functions, or alter hooks; themes cannot implement `hook_user_load()`, `hook_node_update()`, or `hook_menu()`, which are not alter hooks (i.e. hooks whose names end in _alter, such as [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)).

As for implementing a functionality in a theme, or in a module, I would rather implement the functionality in a theme if it is dependent from the theme. If the functionality must be present independently from the theme, then it should be implemented in a module. The latter case is also true when the functionality needs to be implemented when the enabled theme is one between two, or three possible themes.